# Domain of a function with $\ln$

Tags: functions, logarithms

Hy everyone, Im stuck on this assigment now :/

so the function is $f(x) = \ln(x - x^2 +12)$ and I need to get the domain of that function.

I know that $x - x^2 + 12 > 0$, because of $\ln$.
then I seperated $x$'s on left and number on right

$x - x^2 > -12$ and I know that I can also write it as $x(1-x) > -12$

How do I get domain out of this :/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is solving a second degree inequality.

Write it with a positive main coefficient (it is not a "must", but it is quite a "should"):
$$x^2-x-12<0$$
Note that the RHS is $0$. Find the roots and factor the polynomial:
$$(x+3)(x-4)<0$$
Now this product is negative only when the two factors have different signs. This is when $x$ is in the interval $(-3,4)$.

Comment: So when I am solving second degree inequality, I need to get "< 0" (in this case "> 0" brings complex numbers) always if I want to calculate it using quadratic formula ? Also why do you only change C (12) sing when switching > to <, why not also A(x) and B(x_tothepowerof_2)?

Answer (score 0):

You can study the parabola, find its roots. There will be a small part where it is positive $\Delta=1+48=49=7^2$
Hence you have the roots and yu know it will be positive between them.

Answer (score 0):

solving the inequality $$-x^2+x+12>0$$ we get $$-3<x<4$$ and for $y$ we obtain $$-\infty<y\le \log\left(\frac{49}{4}\right)$$

Comment: once I get x1 = -3 and x2 = 4, how do I know that its -3 < x < 4 and not ( x < -3 && x > 4)

Comment: plot the parabola $$f(x)=-x^2+x+12$$ and you can compute the Maximum Point by calculus

Comment: I just learned that when A(x to the power is 2) is positive parabola is upwarsd and when negative its upwards, and I got x1 = -3 and x2 = 4 by calculating x from x_ttp_2 - x -12 < 0, so my parabola is upwards and its "< 0" so I should look at parabola area below X axis, right ?